# Return nodes only without relationship in graph view Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My Neo4j 3 have nodes and relationships , I have to view all the nodes without relationship in graph view . I used `Match(n) return n` but it returned all the nodes and relationship. How to view only the nodes without relationship ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should return all nodes that have no relationships at all

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT (n)--()
RETURN n;
```

Is that what you are asking, or do you just want to see nodes in the console without having their relationships displayed? If this is the case there is a setting you can check to turn off `Connect Results Node` in the browser console:

[image]

Comment: ,I want to return all nodes which can have or cannot have relationships, but should only return nodes .

Comment: See update @Raju, maybe this is what you're looking for?

Comment: yes @Mark_M that's what I asked . By un marking the connect result nodes .Thank you